# Install CGAL in visual studio with error Unable to start program libCGAL-vc120-mt-gd-4.5.lib

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cgal

I have tried to install CGAL, maybe I installed it correctly but I don't know how to create a project Hello World in VS.
When I pasted some lines of code to file .cpp CGAL project:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/convex_hull_2.h>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::Point_2 Point_2;
int main()
{
Point_2 points[5] = { Point_2(0, 0), Point_2(10, 0), Point_2(10, 10), Point_2(6, 5), Point_2(4, 1) };
Point_2 result[5];
Point_2 *ptr = CGAL::convex_hull_2(points, points + 5, result);
std::cout << ptr - result << " points on the convex hull:" << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < ptr - result; i++){
    std::cout << result[i] << std::endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

I built this code with no error, But when I ran this code in Release mode here the error: **Unable to start the program :'C:\CGAL\lib\Release\libCGAL-vc120-mt-45.lib'**

In Debug mode: **Unable to start the program :'C:\CGAL\lib\Debug\libCGAL-vc120-mt-gd-45.lib'**
Please tell me how to fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you successfully build the library?
It is explained [here](https://www.cgal.org/windows_installation.html) in Building CGAL section. It then generates the lib files such as C:\CGAL\lib\Release\libCGAL-vc120-mt-45.lib. If it generates the .lib files with a different name (libCGAL-vc-120-mt-45.lib instead of vc120 for instance) try renaming the .lib file with the libCGAL-vc120-mt-45.lib (it worked for me).

Comment: I have both of files and correct names, but visual still said that cannot run program.

Comment: Were you able to compile some demos?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean? I can compile some demo

Comment: And example too, but I have the same problem